# Scala eclipse plugin Problem

Tags: scala, compiler-construction, eclipse-plugin

I install the scala eclipse plugin, but it make me annoyed

It cannot compile correctly， it indicate compiling error for the following statement

```
job setMapperClass classOf[ASPMapReduce.Map]
```

**type mismatch; found : java.lang.Classcom.ebay.twitch.ASPMapReduce.Map required: java.lang.Class[_ <: 
 org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper]**

But actually ASPMapReduce.Map is really a sub class of org.apache.hadoop.mapreeuce.Mapper
And I can use maven to compile it succesffuly. but eclipse always tell me the compiling error

What's wrong with the scala eclipse plugin ? BTW I use the  Scala IDE 2.0.0-beta4 with Scala 2.9.0.final for Eclipse 3.6

Comment: Such problems are really better discussed on the [Scala IDE mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/scala-ide-user/topics), especially considering that the Scala IDE is still in beta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question appears to have the same root cause as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028221/how-does-one-implement-a-hadoop-mapper-in-scala-2-9-0.).  That question spawned [this ticket](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4603?focusedCommentId=53488&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-53488) against Scala.

**Update:** This bug is fixed in Scala 2.9.1 RC2

You can workaround the problem by using Scala 2.8.1 (boo) or, silly as it seems, defining the Mapper before the Job.  The following compiles:

```
import org.apache.hadoop._
import org.apache.hadoop.io._
import org.apache.hadoop.conf._
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce._

class MyMapper extends Mapper[LongWritable,Text,Text,Text] {
  override def map(key: LongWritable, value: Text, context: Mapper[LongWritable,Text,Text,Text]#Context) {
  }
}

object MyJob {
  def main(args:Array[String]) {
    val job = new Job(new Configuration())
    job.setMapperClass(classOf[MyMapper])
  }
}
```